# Prevent progressive (line by line) loading of background image

Tags: css, load, background-image

I am looking for a way to have the background-images (CSS) load as if they were appearing once loaded, and not "rolling down". I'd rather have an image appear 300ms late in one flash instead of having it appear like a bad PowerPoint effect.

Any techniques or specific code that could be used (besides caching)?

Thanks,

Comment: How big is the image? I can totally see that happening if the image is 1mb+.

Comment: there are 8 images, all +/- 60Kb

Comment: Waoh, those are pretty small, how fast is your connection that you see the images scan-line in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if your image appear in "rolling down" it's Image it's too heavy.

Exist different program or website for reduce your image for web ( without losing quality ) 
for sample, [Yahoo SMUSH.IT!](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/smushit/) is good for that!

After, I don't know if existing a method for appear background-image after download... maybe in JavaScript...

Answer (score 3):

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9fFKT/3/

```
$("#bg").hide();
$('#bg').load(function(){

  $('#bg').show();
});
```

using jquery you can hide until it loads and display it once its loaded

Comment: Extended version: you can do this, and for example put some compressed and smaller version of bg image while big bg loading, and exchange backgrounds when loading of big bg-image is finished.

Comment: Important to note that this solution is using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you'd need to either have the elements hidden on initial load, or to have **no** background set in CSS, add the image via JavaScript, then apply the CSS background with the onload event of each image.

CSS alone cannot do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could load the image as hidden at the top of your page, so when you put it into the DOM later it is a cached copy. Or, you can put a hidden attribute on it, and after a 300ms timer, turn hidden off. The latter will do what you want with more certainty, but it depends on your viewers network speeds.